# How do I display something when a cookie expires

Tags: asp.net

I'm wanting to show a video when a person comes to the site and doesn't have a cookie. After they see the video, a cookie is added, but when the cookie expires, the video is played again.

```
if (Request.Cookies["x"] != null)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        Response.Cookies["x"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["x"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
    }
```

I would think this would work correctly, however the movie only shows if the browser is cleared of all cookies. 24hrs later the movie will not play.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the cookie is null AND if it has expired.  Obviously, the cookie is still on the user's browser, but expired and doing nothing.

```
if (Request.Cookies["x"] != null && Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Cookies["x"].Expires) > DateTime.Now)
{  

    // do nothing
}
else
{
   // your other code


}
```

Comment: While that is probably the case, it seems wrong. You should not be able to get the value of an expired cookie, both the browser and framework should be handling this.

Comment: I was reading about cookies a while ago and when they expire, the cookies are supposed to be deleted. That's why I never checked for an expired cookie.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Request.Cookies["x"] != null && Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Cookies["x"].Expires) < DateTime.Now)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        Response.Cookies["x"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["x"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
    }
```

He was correct but the logic was a little wrong.